# Is it worth including external decoding libraries for AAC and OGG mainly?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm decoding AAC, OGG, and ASF/ASX/WMA/MMS type data using FFmpeg. I'm wondering if It is recommended to include external libraries to the FFmpeg build? Or is the latest FFmpeg release project contains the best and efficient decoders and there really isn't any need to include other libraries?

Comment: doesn't FFmpeg basically require libtheora for parsing ogg?  Anyway I'd say, if one way works, go with it till if fails, then try the other :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well, I'm not sure if libtheora is more stable for parsing ogg? Knowing that would help decide if it is worth the effort to compile those libs with ffmpeg.

Comment: AFAIK libtheora is a bit better, though you could ask the FFmpeg maintainers I guess...

Comment: If you are distributing your build note that some external AAC encoders require `--enable-nonfree` which means that they are, "not compatible with the GPL and distribution of binaries containing code licensed under these licenses when GPL-licensed code is also included is not permitted" [[1](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide)].

Comment: You only need external libraries for AAC or Vorbis (I assume you mean Vorbis for OGG) audio decoding if the native encoders do not support a feature that the external decoders do support (what may be unsupported at the moment I do not know).

Comment: I'm simply decoding audio. I guess there is no gain with using external AAC library but I'm not yet sure about Vorbis for OGG and the mms and mmsh protocol support. If I should use external libs for those.

Comment: You do not need external libraries to decode Vorbis audio or to use MMS as an input protocol.